# Java, covert recusrion into one loop

Tags: java, recursion

I want to convert this method into one loop, any kind of loop is fine i find it hard to convert from recursion.

```
public class Problem5
    {
     public double getRoot(double a, double b)
     {
      double x = (a + b)/2;

      if (b - a <= 0.00)
       return x;

      double y = getValue(x);

      if(y < 0)
       return getRoot(x, b);
      else
       return getRoot(a, x);
     }
```

Comment: have you checked google for examples of recursion versus iteration?

Answer (score 0):

```
public double getRoot(double a, double b) {
    while (true) {
        double x = (a + b)/2;

        if (b - a <= 0.00)
            return x;

        double y = getValue(x);

        if(y < 0) 
            a = x;
        else 
            b = x;
    }
    throw new AssertionError("should not happen");
}
```